# CentOS 6.5 Installation

Tags: centos, system-installation

I am currently trying to install CentOS 6.5 (LiveDVD from bootable USB) on an HP Z4 G4 Workstation, however, due to a hardware compatibility issue, the text version is installed.

The GUI is required for this but due to company policy we cannot connect it to the internet, so I cannot use the `yum` command to update or install any desktop packages.

I've tried disabling the nouveau driver after running into the following error:

```
conflicting fb hw usage nouveaufb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
```

but this did not work.

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, however, I suspect it may be the video card.

When trying to install LiveDVD1 from bootable USB, I run into "`X startup failed, switching to text mode`".

I've also had an issue with booting the LiveDVD version where the installation process hangs on "`waiting for hardware to initialize`"

Comment: Please provide minimal details about the hardware compatibility issue.

Comment: You may get some some info from dmesg or journalctl.

Comment: Are you absolutely required to use an unsupported version of CentOS?  Maybe a supported release would support you hardware?

Comment: We ended up going with a more recent version of CentOS and it worked, CentOS 6.5 is really outdated.